# MongoDB Sharding Configuration

Tags: mongodb, connectivity

I am trying to setup a sharding on Windows Server 2008 R2. I have a batch file in which i added the following commands:

[image]

When I try to connect to mongos with the default port, I get an error
(unable to connect).

Here is the log file:

```
Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:26051 after 5000ms milliseconds, giving up.
Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:26052 after 5000ms milliseconds, giving up.
No primary detected for set confRS
All nodes for set confRS are down. This has happened for 1 checks in a row.
Error initializing sharding state, sleeping for 2 seconds and trying again :: caused by :: FailedToSatisfyReadPreference: Error loading clusterID :: caused by :: could not find host matching read preference { mode: "nearest" } for set confRS
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes.. First, adding pictures is not good idea, I could not see all lines from the picture, it is better to insert (text) copy & paste with "code" tags.

1. Please add `--replicaSet confRS` parameter to config server lines.
2. Fix ALL mongos `--configdb confRS/localhost:26050,localhost:26051,localhost:26052
3. You don't need mongos for every shard. You can run whole system with ONE mongos and when you have one mongos, you don't need to give `--port` because it will use port 27017
4. Connect to that mongos with command `mongo` and register you shards and shard you connections...

..and with `--fork` (mongod; config and shard) you get your processes to run background...

---

Have you connected (with `mongo`) to every replica set and created that replica set (shard and config) with `rs.initiate()`

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/

after that when you have all those replica set running successful, you can create that cluster (add shards to config server).